# Where do I get the bearer token for the youtube api?

Tags: oauth, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I'm trying to send a youtube live stream message and I can't figure out where to get the bearer token.

Comment: The documentation of this API Token is terrible. You can try here : https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/. But you will need to refresh tokens, and for it never works.

Comment: Is there some way I could use my API key instead?

Comment: API key doesn't work with some functionalities (upload video, upload stream), you must use OAuth2. And believe me, it's pretty hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized I had to use this script to get the bearer token: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs and then use the google api to a get a new token every so often.